# How can I size a dygraph widget properly within a flexdashboard tabset layout in shiny?

Tags: r, tabs, shiny, dygraphs, flexdashboard

In R, I'm creating a `shiny` app with a `flexdashboard` layout that uses tabs.
I want to include a `dygraph` in one of the tabs but the chart goes out of the container.
I tried changing the width and the height both in the `dygraph` and in the output but none of them seem to work.

Minimum working example:

````
---
title: "Example"
output: 
flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
orientation: columns
vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

```{r global, include=FALSE}
library(dygraphs)
data=data.frame(x=1:10,y=11:20,val=21:30)

ymin=min(data$y,na.rm=TRUE)
ymax=max(data$y,na.rm=TRUE)

```

TABS {.tabset}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Tab1



```{r singleSlider }
sliderInput("sliceval", "Observation:",
            min = ymin, max = ymax,step=1,
            value = 11,width="90%")



```

```{r dygraph}

# Tried also changing height width to px
output$sliceGraph <- renderDygraph({
  dygraph(data[input$sliceval>=data$y,c("x","val")],height="50%",width="80%")
})

# Tried also changing height width to %
dygraphOutput("sliceGraph",height='100px',width='100px')


```

### Tab 2 

Some stuff here
````

Is there a way to fit the `dygraph` properly in such a layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd take a look at the [documentation for using flexdashboard](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/shiny.html#advanced) again and use their recommended `fillCol` or `fillRow` to exercise more control.  Specifically, try this layout:

````
```{r singleSlider, echo=FALSE}
fillCol(height = 600, flex = c(NA, 1),
  sliderInput("sliceval", "Observation:",
            min = ymin, max = ymax,step=1,
            value = 11,width="90%"),
  # Tried also changing height width to %
  dygraphOutput("sliceGraph",height='400px',width='100%')
)


# Tried also changing height width to px
output$sliceGraph <- renderDygraph({
  dygraph(data[input$sliceval>=data$y,c("x","val")],height="50%",width="80%")
})
```
````

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had read the example but I wasn't able to put it into practice.

Comment: Fair enough. I mostly just played around with the CSS heights until I found something that looked reasonable.