# How can I adjust the size of my Highcharter subplots within a flexdashboard that uses Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard, r-highcharter

I'm trying to display `highcharter` subplots, using `hw_grid()`, within a `flexdashboard` that uses Shiny.

Both rows of subplots appear properly within a static `flexdashboard` document:

[image: hw_grid within a static flex dashboard document.]

I can adjust the size of the subplots by changing the `rowheight` argument of `hw_grid()`.

However, when I use Shiny within `flexdashboard` (by adding `runtime: shiny` to the YAML header), the `rowheight` argument is ignored and the second row of the subplots is not displayed fully within the container:

[image: hw_grid within flexdashboard that uses Shiny.]

How can I replicate the first output within a `flexdashboard` that uses Shiny?

Here is the code for the static document that displays the subplots properly:

````
    ---
    title: "hw_grid flexdashboard"
    output: 
      flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
        vertical_layout: scroll
        orientation: rows
    ---

    ```{r setup, include = FALSE}
    library(flexdashboard)
    library(shiny)
    library(tibble)
    library(dplyr)
    library(highcharter)
    ```

    ```{r read data, include = FALSE}
    data <- 
      structure(list(date = structure(c(18806, 18806, 18806, 18806, 
      18806, 18806, 18806, 18806, 18807, 18807, 18807, 18807, 18807, 
      18807, 18807, 18807, 18808, 18808, 18808, 18808, 18808, 18808, 
      18808, 18808), class = "Date"), value = c(108.8, 138, 90.1, 97.4, 
      79, 85.7, 74.6, 73.4, 108.8, 144.9, 80.6, 99.7, 75.8, 78.9, 73.9, 
      76.8, 109.2, 126.6, 81.6, 100.2, 74.4, 81.2, 73.5, 78.5), category = c("A", 
      "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", 
      "G", "H", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
      "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -24L))
    ```

    Row
    -------------------------------------

    ### hw_grid flexdashboard

    ```{r subplots}
      data %>%
        group_by(category) %>%
        group_map( ~ {
          .x %>%
            hchart("line", hcaes(x = date, y = value))
        }) %>%
        # rowheight adjusts the size of the subplots.
        hw_grid(ncol = 4, rowheight = "220px", browsable = TRUE)
    ```
````

Here is the code for the `flexdashboard` that uses Shiny:

````
    ---
    title: "hw_grid flexdashboard with Shiny"
    runtime: shiny
    output: 
      flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
        vertical_layout: scroll
        orientation: rows
    ---

    ```{r setup, include = FALSE}
    library(flexdashboard)
    library(shiny)
    library(tibble)
    library(dplyr)
    library(highcharter)
    ```

    ```{r read data, include = FALSE}
    data <- 
      structure(list(date = structure(c(18806, 18806, 18806, 18806, 
      18806, 18806, 18806, 18806, 18807, 18807, 18807, 18807, 18807, 
      18807, 18807, 18807, 18808, 18808, 18808, 18808, 18808, 18808, 
      18808, 18808), class = "Date"), value = c(108.8, 138, 90.1, 97.4, 
      79, 85.7, 74.6, 73.4, 108.8, 144.9, 80.6, 99.7, 75.8, 78.9, 73.9, 
      76.8, 109.2, 126.6, 81.6, 100.2, 74.4, 81.2, 73.5, 78.5), category = c("A", 
      "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", 
      "G", "H", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
      "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -24L))
    ```

    Row
    -------------------------------------

    ### hw_grid Shiny Issue

    ```{r subplots}
    output$chart <- renderUI({
      data %>%
        group_by(category) %>%
        group_map(~ {
          .x %>%
            hchart("line", hcaes(x = date, y = value))
        }) %>%
        hw_grid(ncol = 4,
                rowheight = "220px",  # rowheight does nothing here
                browsable = TRUE)
    })

    htmlOutput('chart')
    ```
````

What I've tried so far:

1. Setting the knitr `fig.height` option in the chunk.
2. Modifying row height (e.g., `Row {height=300}`).
3. Implementing `fillCol` and `fillRow` based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46951553/how-can-i-size-a-dygraph-widget-properly-within-a-flexdashboard-tabset-layout-in), which doesn't seem to adjust the actual size of the subplots:

```
    fillCol(height = 400,
        flex = c(NA, 1),
        output$chart <- renderUI({
          data %>%
            group_by(category) %>%
            group_map( ~ {
              .x %>%
                hchart("line", hcaes(x = date, y = value))
            }) %>%
            hw_grid(ncol = 4,
                    rowheight = "220px",
                    browsable = TRUE)
        }))

     htmlOutput('chart')
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Mihail Unfortunately no.

Comment: Do you think that something like the following, could be implemented and work?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51595824/resize-plot-in-shiny-dynamically